# Mean Value Theorem Problem - finding $\xi$ given $f$ and $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods, roots

For the function $f(x) = x^{6}+x^{4}-1$ and the interval $[0,1]$, I need to find the number $\xi$ that occurs in the Mean Value Theorem: $\displaystyle \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{(b-a)} = f^{\prime}(\xi)$.

Plugging in all the given information, I get that $\displaystyle \frac{f(1) - f(0)}{1-0} = 6\xi^{5} + 4\xi^{3} \to \frac{(1^{6}+1^{4}-1)-(0^{6}-0^{4}-1)}{1} = 6\xi^{5} + 4\xi^{3} \to 2 =6\xi^{5} + 4\xi^{3} \to 1 = 3\xi^{5} + 2\xi^{3} \to 3\xi^{5} + 2\xi^{3} - 1= 0 $

So, this amounts to finding a root of the polynomial $3\xi^{5} + 2\xi^{3} - 1= 0 $ such that $0 < \xi < 1$

Using the rational roots theorem, the only possibility is that $\displaystyle \xi = \frac{1}{3}$; however, when I plug it into the equation $3\xi^{5} + 2\xi^{3} - 1= 0 $, I find that it does not give me a true statement.

Therefore, I am at an impasse to find the $\xi$ I'm looking for. Any assistance you could offer would be most welcomed - although the more detailed and concrete, the better. Thanks!

Comment: I think that the equation $3\xi^5+2\xi^3-1=0$ will be very difficult to solve in terms of square roots, but I might be wrong. I don't see any problem with your solution, so maybe the question was not intended to be this one?

Comment: No, that's it. In the morning, I'm going to throw it into Maple and see what it gives me. But, I'm pretty sure we were meant to solve this problem analytically, not numerically.

Comment: According to WolframAlpha you have only one real root $x\approx 0.668849$, it didn't give an exact form. Do you really have to find the exact $\xi$?

Comment: In my text, this is supposed to be exactly like the one that came before it (they call it a "continuation problem"), and for that one, you were able to solve for an exact $\xi$.  FYI - it's from Kincaid & Cheney's Numerical Analysis text - problem 1.1.14.

Comment: Please rectify the typo as follows. Replace  $$\frac{(1^{6}+1^{4}-1)+(0^{6}-0^{4}-1)}{1}$$ by $$\frac{(1^{6}+1^{4}-1)-(0^{6}-0^{4}-1)}{1}$$

Comment: In the copy in our library, it is question 1.11, and the exact text is "Repeat Problem 4 with the function $f(x)=x^6+x^4-1$ and the interval $[0,1]$." Maybe the intention behind this question is to remind the reader that the mean value theorem is an existence theorem, and that, in fact, it is often impossible to find the $\xi$.

Comment: @DeepakGupta, done. .

Comment: @mickep, I think you're probably right. I'm going to ask my prof about it though just to make sure.